# EntityFramework Migration Specify web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using MV4 and EF5. Is there a way to have EntityFramework Migration pull the connection string from web.debug.config or web.release.config.

Running update-database seems to throw an error unless the connection string is in web.config

Comment: look into `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because web.config is where the connection string should be found. `Web.release.config` and `Web.debug.config` are configuration transformations based on the current "Solution Configuration". See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_webdevelopment_topic4.aspx) for details.

The short answer is, of course the connection string is expected to be in Web.config, because that's where it's designed to live.

You can use the -ConnectionStringName or -ConnectionString parameter on Update-Database to specify a different connection for the migrations.

Comment: does this mean it *cannot* be in a transformation config?